# How to get value from useLazyAsyncData?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using `useLazyAsyncData` to fetch data like below:

```
<template>
  <pre v-if="!pending">
  {{ report }}
  </pre>
</template>

<script setup>

const {
  data: report,
  pending,
  error,
} = useLazyAsyncData("report", () =>
  $fetch("http://api.test/foo")
);

console.log(report);
console.log(report.value);

</script>
```

I'm getting a result looking like this:

```
{
    "__v_isShallow": false,
    "dep": {
        "w": 0,
        "n": 0
    },
    "__v_isRef": true,
    "_rawValue": "{}",
    "_value": "{}"
}
```

How to get the json value instead ?
And should I add `await` before `useLazyAsyncData` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can log the `report` value inside watch instead, because `report` is `null` in the beginning. You were essentially logging it before your api returned any value.

However judging from your `<template>` you should be seeing the correct `report` value without any issues.

More info https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-async-data

```
    <template>
      <pre v-if="!pending">
      {{ report }}
      </pre>
    </template>

    <script setup>
    const {
      data: report,
      pending,
      error,
    } = useLazyAsyncData("report", () =>
      $fetch("http://api.test/foo")
    );

    console.log(report);
    console.log(report.value);

    watch(report, (newReport) => {
      // Because report starts out null, you won't have access
      // to its contents immediately, but you can watch it.
      console.log(newReport);
    })
    </script>
```